# How to send an image to http request?

Tags: python, http, wsgi

Making a WSGI app.
When the browser sees the connected files -

```
<script src="static/js/func.js"></script>
```

it makes a request to receive them and I can give text files to my function:

```
def giveFile(environ, start_response):

    headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/html')]
    status = '404 NOT FOUND'
    file = ''

    if os.path.exists(environ['PATH_INFO'][1:]):
        status = '200 OK'
        with open(environ['PATH_INFO'][1:], encoding='utf-8') as res:
            file = res.read()
        if 'js' in environ['url_args']:
            headers = [('Content-Type', 'application/javascript')]
        elif 'css' in environ['url_args']:
            headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/css')]

    start_response(status, headers)
    return [file.encode()]
```

I read the file with the "open" function and put the result in "return".
The browser also tries to get images "favicon.ico" and others.

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

How do I return an image to the query, what to use for this?